# What is the meaning of "confer order on its listeners"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Here, Mr Carslake’s comparison of the painting to an ‘old English
>   song’ celebrates music’s expressivity and capacity to **confer order on
>   its listeners**, but also evokes the extensive contemporary nationalist
>   writing about English folk song, landscape and early music by the
>   composers and teachers of the English Musical Renaissance.
>   (...)
>   Yet Mr Carslake’s belief that music **confers** ‘proportion’ on the listener echoes the catchphrase used by the unfeeling doctors treating shell-shocked war veterans in her contemporary novel Mrs Dalloway, using music to suggest a more troubling aspect to his fantasies about communication...

Source: https://publicdomainreview.org/2013/01/09/simple-songs-virginia-woolf-and-music/

This article is about Virginia Woolf and her interest in music. Does "confer order on its listeners" means that music is guiding people to a more orderly life or it's just suggesting that music have a harmony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really mean either of those things; it suggests that music has an effect similar to that of the painting Mr Carslake looks at in the passage from Virginia Woolf's "A Simple Melody" that this scholar (Emma Sutton) is referring to:

Mr Carslake, at least, thought [the painting] very beautiful because, *as he stood in the corner where he could see it, it had the power to compose and tranquillize his mind* [emphasis added]. It seemed to him *to bring the rest of his emotions – and how scattered and jumbled they were at a party like this! – into proportion* [emphasis added]. It was as if a fiddler were playing a perfectly quiet old English song while people gambled and tumbled and swore, picked pockets, rescued the drowning, and did astonishing – but quite unnecessary – feats of skill.

According to Sutton's analysis, Woolf's narrator takes it for granted that listening to music has the capacity to bring *temporary* balance, order, and tranquility to the mind of the listener, even in the midst of chaos, and the narrator tells us that looking at the painting has a similar effect on Mr Carslake. When Sutton refers to "music's… capacity to confer order on its listeners," it is this idea of *temporary* order and tranquility that she is invoking – not the idea that music guides people to a more orderly life.